# Variables of two functions are not working together

Tags: javascript, function

I have a little bit problem while using variables of two functions together. In this both functions are not working at once.
Here are my two functions :

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " red";
}


var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs2(slideIndex);

function plusDivs2(n) {
  showDivs2(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv2(n) {
  showDivs2(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs2(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo2");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " red";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.mySlides2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.i-am-bhaskar.com/panel/assets/img/blogs/43288.png" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.i-am-bhaskar.com/panel/assets/img/blogs/17874.jpg" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.i-am-bhaskar.com/panel/assets/img/blogs/blog.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
</div>

<div class="center">
  <div class="section">
    <button class="button light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button>
    <button class="button light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content2">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://www.i-am-bhaskar.com/panel/assets/img/blogs/43288.png" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://www.i-am-bhaskar.com/panel/assets/img/blogs/17874.jpg" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://www.i-am-bhaskar.com/panel/assets/img/blogs/blog.jpg" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;">
</div>

<div class="center">
  <div class="section">
    <button class="button light-grey" onclick="plusDivs2(-1)">❮ Prev</button>
    <button class="button light-grey" onclick="plusDivs2(1)">Next ❯</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this, I have two div containing images with next and prev button, images of first function is loading by default but when i click on button then second image is appear. I just want to fix it i.e images of both div will load default.

Comment: line 25 add `if (dots.length > 0)` to check before `dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " red";` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/7dqvhust/)

Comment: can you please check on jsfiddle link :  https://jsfiddle.net/Bhawesh7731/jbLragoz/8/

Comment: yes, you can add an `if` to check the length of `dots` array, refer the fiddle above, same in `showDivs2`

Comment: thanks dude, it was just a blunder from my side,

Comment: did that helped?

Comment: yes, it helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: *help. kewl kewl